# How to dynamically generate Includes in entity framework

Tags: c#, methods, entity-framework-4

Well I am not sure if this questions asked before but I have no idea how the search for it. Well this is not an Entity Framework specified question but I am gonna give example using it.

So in EF we need to use `.Include("Related Object")` to include related data. However what I want to is that write a method that takes a List of strings and returns the entity or entity list with the related objects.

In example

```
public List<Entity> GetAll(List<string> includes>)
{
     List<Entity> entites = context.Entites;
     foreach(string s in includes)
     {
          entites.Include(s);
     }
     return entites;
}
```

Obviously above example won't work since I already called out the Entites when I declared the list. But I think it demonstrates the point.

Comment: You could use a better title for your question :)  Some thing like `How to dynamically generate Includes in entity framework` or something like that.  And you might want to add the `entity-framework` tag to your question.

Comment: Well that's a better title for sure. :) But this is not a EF specified question but you might be right though.

Comment: I took your advice. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare your local variable as `DbQuery<Entity>`, reassign result of `Include` call to it and call `ToList` on it after the loop:

```
public List<Entity> GetAll(List<string> includes>)
{
     DbQuery<Entity> entites = context.Entites;
     foreach(string s in includes)
     {
          entities = entites.Include(s);
     }
     return entites.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I am giving it a try.